# How to scrape text from this site using beautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is an example link but I am trying to scrape from the [Pokemoncenter website](https://www.pokemoncenter.com/product/701-06765/yamper-poke-plush-21-1-2-in).

I want to scrape the price of the item but I am not getting anything.

```
prices = soup.find_all('span',attrs={'class':'jsx-1022525614 product-price-value'})
for price in prices:
    print(price.text)
```

This prints a blank line.

I tried

```
    for price in prices:
        ItemPrice = price.string
        print(ItemPrice)
```

And it prints "None"

Comment: The span is itself blank, do u need the titles?

Comment: Are you using `requests`? If so try printing everything and see if it works, if it's also blank then that means it's not a static site so you're going to have to use Selenium

Comment: @WasifHasan I need the price and product title. I got the Title to work but the price I cannot get. I can see the price in several locations in the HTML code but I am unsure how to get it.

Comment: @F.M Yes I am using requests. See my above comment

Answer (score 0):

The price value is producted with javascript in opening the site, so the raw html doesn't have the value.